# In handsontable after select a day from date picker new row added

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, handsontable

I'm using handsontable version 10, I have a issue after selecting a date from date picker it will added a new row. How I can disable that? But I need to get a new row with "enter key"

any one can test with this code,

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var container2 = document.getElementById('example2'),
hot2;


hot2 = new Handsontable(container2, {
data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(5, 5),
colHeaders: true,
minSpareRows: 1,
columns: [
    {
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        correctFormat: true,
        datePickerConfig: {
            firstDay: 0,
            showWeekNumber: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
            disableDayFn(date) {
                // Disable Sunday and Saturday
                return date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6;
            }
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'text',
    },
    {

    },
    {

    }
    ]  });});
```

Comment: remove minsparerows http://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/react-jsx

Answer (score 1):

In your settings, there's a `minSpareRows: 1` which adds a new line in the table each time you feel **any** of those cells in the last row

[image: Handsontable adds a new row with minSpareRows]

so when you pick a date in the cell index `5` app automatically adds a new row.

Comment: Thanks for explain, I thought it was a issue with date picker.